# Failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:NoNo)

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I've been trying to create a new database connection on workbench. However, every time I test a connection there is an error message that says
Failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root
unable to connect localhost

Answer (score 0):

finally I get it by installing MySQL installer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).